# how to tag multiple elements?

Tags: html, css

here's somethign I'm trying to do.

I have a site where all the "a" tags have a blue link style. I have a header with a link in it that I want to remove the default blue link from it and make it an orange color. Here's how it looks right now:

```
<h1 class="site-name">
       <a href="/" title="Home" class="active">MySite.com</a>
</h1>
```

so basically I want to write some CSS that will make my "MySite.com" have an orange color and not have the default blue link that you are familar with. I don't want to change the "a" style because I don't want every single link to have this, only this one.

i managed to style part of the way there by doing,

```
h1.site-name {        
font-size:36px;
         text-decoration:none;
         color:#ff5312;
     }
```

however, i see in the css it updated using firebug, but it didn't change the link color. then i tried

```
h1.site-name.a
```

but that didn't work. what do i have to do to reach this "a" tag here, but only this tag to make it look the way I want?

thanks for any insights.

Comment: The trick is that `a` isn't a class, it's a tag. Only classes are preceded with a `.` (just as only IDs are preceded by a `#`).

Comment: have to wait 10 minutes until i can accept an answer.. but will be accepting his once it lets me of course..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `h1.site-name.a` with

```
h1.site-name a
```

You dont need to put `.` here.Because it is not a `class` it is a tag.

```
 h1.site-name a{        
     font-size:36px;
     text-decoration:none;
     color:red;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`h1.site-name a` or just `.site-name a`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `h1.site-name a` instead of `h1.site-name.a`

```
h1.site-name a{        
font-size:36px;
         text-decoration:none;
         color:red;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
h1.site-name a {        
         font-size:36px;
         text-decoration:none;
         color:red;
     }
```

This will find `<a></a>` tag in side `<h1></h1>`.